# How to create a list with several lists python

Tags: python, list

**I have these 3 lists :**

**list1** (question):

```
['Which of the following would best describe the meaning of value in a shippable increment?(choose the best two answers)', 'The Scrum Team consists of: (choose all that apply)']
```

**list2** (correct) : (list of list)

```
[['It is likely to increase customer engagement and happiness with the product.', 'It reduces long-term operational costs.'], ['The Developers', 'The Scrum Master', 'The Product Owner']]
```

**list3** (incorrect) : (list of list)

```
[['It has all User Stories that were committed to at the Sprint Planning.', 'It is completed on time.', 'It is approved by the Product Owner at the Sprint Review.'], ['The Key Stakeholders']]
```

**I want to create a  list that will contains these 3 lists it should look like that** :

```
[{'question': 'Which of the following would best describe the meaning of value in a shippable increment?(choose the best two answers)',
  'correct': ['It is likely to increase customer engagement and happiness with the product',
   'It reduces long-term operational costs.'],
  'incorrect': ['It has all User Stories that were committed to at the Sprint Planning.',
   'It is completed on time.]},

{'question': 'The Scrum Team consists of: (choose all that apply)',
  'correct': ['The Developers',
   'The Scrum Master',
   'The Product Owner'],
  'incorrect': ['The Key Stakeholders']} ]
```

***so for each question, we get the correct answer(s) and incorrect answer(s)
and need to add "question :"   / "correct:" / "incorrect" as well.
if anyone could help me please***

Comment: Post your code, along with a specific question about what's giving you trouble.

Comment: you can use `zip` multiple times for this. first zip will help segregate corresponding elements from each list. Next you can use zip with the key names for each element in the iterator from first zip and convert to a dictionary. This will result in what you are looking for. Check my answer for details and code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say the best solution is:

```py
lol = [{'question': x[0], 'correct': x[1], 'incorrect': x[2]} for x in zip(list1, list2, list3)]
```

The idea is to `zip()` the list, it's a function that takes a couple (1+) of iterables/containers and joins them into one list. For example:

```py
In [1]: list(zip([1, 2], [3, 4]))                                                                                                                                       
Out[1]: [(1, 3), (2, 4)]
```

And from here, we just iterate over the zipped list, and from each tuple, we create a dict.

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach with multiple uses of `zip`. This would work in the following way (refer diagram for visual intuition) -

[image]

1. First, zip each corresponding element in each of the 3 lists. This will result in a list with 2 items, where each item is a tuple with 3 elements (Q, C, I)
2. Second, zip the keys (containing key names/variable names) with each element of the above zip object. This will result in `(Q0, C0, I0)` zipped with `["question", "correct", "incorrect"]` to look like `[("question",Q0), ("correct":C0), ("incorrect":I0)]` and same for `(Q1, C1, I1)`.
3. Finally `dict()` will convert this into key, value pairs like you are looking for.

```
question = ['Which of the following would best describe the meaning of value in a shippable increment?(choose the best two answers)', 'The Scrum Team consists of: (choose all that apply)']
correct = [['It is likely to increase customer engagement and happiness with the product.', 'It reduces long-term operational costs.'], ['The Developers', 'The Scrum Master', 'The Product Owner']]
incorrect = [['It has all User Stories that were committed to at the Sprint Planning.', 'It is completed on time.', 'It is approved by the Product Owner at the Sprint Review.'], ['The Key Stakeholders']]
keys = ["question", "correct", "incorrect"]

output = [dict(zip(keys,i)) for i in zip(question, correct, incorrect)] #<-----

print("First dictionary")
print(output[0])
print("Second dictionary")
print(output[1])
```

```
First dictionary
{'question': 'Which of the following would best describe the meaning of value in a shippable increment?(choose the best two answers)', 
 'correct': ['It is likely to increase customer engagement and happiness with the product.', 'It reduces long-term operational costs.'], 
 'incorrect': ['It has all User Stories that were committed to at the Sprint Planning.', 'It is completed on time.', 'It is approved by the Product Owner at the Sprint Review.']}


Second dictionary
{'question': 'The Scrum Team consists of: (choose all that apply)', 
 'correct': ['The Developers', 'The Scrum Master', 'The Product Owner'], 
 'incorrect': ['The Key Stakeholders']}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can nest Python lists by just nesting them into another.

E.g.

```
nestedList = ['a', ['bb', ['ccc', 'ddd'], 'ee', 'ff'], 'g', 'h']
```

The curly braces you use above usally define dictionaries.

If you still want to go for lists - even though a dict would fit quite nicely - you could go for something like this:

```
[['question1 delimiter answer'], ['question2 delimiter answer'], ... ]
```

or

```
[['question1']['delimiter']['answer'], ....]
```

or

```
[[['question1']['delimiter']['answer']], ....]
```